# how to make comment system on posting with inner join?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to make comment in article. what i need is : username, comment, and id post than every post have different comment. i have 3 table, this below is my table name and it field :

1. `user : id_user, username`
2. `posting : id_user, id_post`
3. `comment : id_com, id_user, id_post, comment`

when i finish make it with my query, i check it by comment in user 1 post using user 2 account. what happend is, comment become posted by user 1.
i use this query below :

```
$query=$dbc->query("SELECT 
                    user.username, 
                    comment.id_com, 
                    comment.comment, 
                    posting.id_post 
                    FROM comment 
                    INNER JOIN (posting INNER JOIN user ON  user.id_user = 
                                 posting.id_user) ON posting.id_post = comment.id_post 
                    WHERE comment.id_post='$_GET[id]'");
```

Comment: @Jens It might be sanitazed...

Comment: @Asur it really makes no difference. Prepares srmtatements are secure. Unprepared statements are not. And there is no way that Get[id] is secure.

Comment: I don't think inserting a variable directly could cause SQLInjection exposure as long as it had been [sanitazed](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) previously. Anyway as I see it that variable is directly taken from a url so you have a point there.

Comment: come on, how about my problem?